# Is there a feature matrix showing which Rust compiler version contains which stable features?

Tags: rust, rustup

I'm currently using `nightly-2022-02-11` installed through rustup, and have enabled a couple of unstable `#![feature(...)]`s in my crate. Now I'm wondering if these features have since become stable, so that I can switch back to the stable channel. Something like [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) but for Rust compilers.

I know I can check the changelogs, tracking issues for each individual feature, etc., but I'm hoping there is an easier way. Some matrix like this (data are fictional):

```
FEATURE                   ... 1.60  1.61  1.62
array_windows                    U     S     S
generic_associated_types         U     U     S
const_fn_trait_bound             -     U     -
...

U = unstable
S = stable
- = not available
```

Ideally this would cover nightly builds as well.

Comment: I think that would be cool. I don't think it exists yet, but I'd be interested in that as well.

Comment: Version numbers such as `1.60` etc are *stable* releases and only support stable features. You'd need to reference nightly versions, e.g. by date, to include unstable features.

Comment: "*Now I'm wondering if these features have since become stable, so that I can switch back to the stable channel*"—when you upgrade your nightly version, e.g. with `rustup update`, a default deny lint will cause compilation to fail if you are enabling a stabilised `#![feature(...)]`.

Comment: `nightly-2022-02-11`—that's really out of date... is there some reason you haven't upgraded?  Are you using a feature that was removed?  Generally speaking, if you're using the nightly toolchain you ought to be updating nightly...

Comment: @eggyal Not all nightlies work equally great, so I tend to stick with what works until I need something newer. But I was looking at upgrading, hence this question :)

Comment: https://caniuse.rs/ seems to cover this, although it is not an official resource.

Comment: Would be useful to integrate this into say clippy or something, that states `this feature got stabilized; upgrade the compiler version and remove the #![feature(...)] flag!`.